# cakephp 2.0 saveAll with getlastid()

Tags: cakephp-2.0

Need your help by solving my problems with saveAll in cakephp 2.0.  I have 3 Models: Datasheet, Datasheetsheading and Datasheetsvalues.  I need the last inserted ID from Datasheet by saving all. I only read from Datasheetsheading...

**My controller:**

```
public function add_datasheet($id = null) {
    $this->set('datasheetsheadings', $this->datasheetsheading->find('all', array('limit' => 0 .','. 9)));
    $this->set('datasheetsheadings2', $this->datasheetsheading->find('all', array('limit' => 9 .','. 9)));
    $this->set('id', $id);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->datasheet->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->datasheetsvalue->saveAll($this->request->data['datasheetsvalue']); 
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your Datasheet >> Lot: ' . $this->request->data['datasheetsvalue'][1]['value'] . ' << has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'Datasheets/' . $this->request->data['datasheet']['id_tbl_articles']));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your datasheet.');
        }
    }
}
```

**My view:**

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('datasheet', array('action' => 'add_datasheet')); ?>
    <fieldset>
        <legend><?php echo __('Neues Datenblatt'); ?></legend>
        <?php
        $value_id = 0;
        echo $this->Form->input('datasheet.comment', array('label' => 'Kommentar')) . '<hr>';
        echo '<div style="width:300px;float:left;">';
        foreach ($datasheetsheadings as $datasheetsheading) :
            $value_id = $value_id +1;
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheet.id_tbl_articles', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $id));
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.id_tbl_articles', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $id));
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.id_tbl_datasheets', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.id_tbl_datasheetsheadings', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $datasheetsheading['datasheetsheading']['id']));
            echo __('<div style="width:140px;color:#FFF;float:left;">' . $datasheetsheading['datasheetsheading']['heading'] . '</div><div style="width:160px;color:#FFF;float:left;text-align:right;">');
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.print', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => 'Im Datenblatt anzeigen', 'style' => 'color:#FFF;'));
            echo '</div><div style="clear:left;"></div><div style="margin-top:-30px;">';
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.value', array('label' => ''));
            echo '</div>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="width:170px;float:left;"></div>';
        echo '<div style="width:300px;float:left;">';
        foreach ($datasheetsheadings2 as $datasheetsheading2) :
            $value_id = $value_id +1;
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheet.id_tbl_articles', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $id));
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.id_tbl_articles', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $id));
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.id_tbl_datasheets', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.id_tbl_datasheetsheadings', array('type' => 'hidden', 'value' => $datasheetsheading2['datasheetsheading']['id']));
            echo __('<div style="width:140px;color:#FFF;float:left;">' . $datasheetsheading2['datasheetsheading']['heading'] . '</div><div style="width:160px;color:#FFF;float:left;text-align:right;">');
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.print', array('type' => 'checkbox', 'label' => 'Im Datenblatt anzeigen', 'style' => 'color:#FFF;'));
            echo '</div><div style="clear:left;"></div><div style="margin-top:-30px;">';
            echo $this->Form->input('datasheetsvalue.' . $value_id . '.value', array('label' => ''));
            echo '</div>';
        endforeach;
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<div style="clear:left;"></div>';
        echo $this->Form->end(__('Sichern'));
    ?>
    </fieldset>
```

By saving a datasheet it stores in datasheet table: `id(auto_increment)`, `id_tbl_articles`, `comment`, `created`, `modified`. This works perfectly!
In datasheetsvalue table i get the values: `id(auto_increment)`, `id_tbl_datasheetsheadings`, `id_tbl_articles`, `values` and `print`. Only at `id_tbl_datasheets` i get `NULL`. I tried a lot with `$hasOne`, `$hasMany`, `$belongsTo`, etc. To set the value `id_tbl_datasheets` to `$this->datasheet->getlastid()` too. Nothing works!!! When i change `saveAll` to `save` i get the correct values, but only one. So i need the function `saveAll`.
Google is your friend and found, that i can't use `getLastId()` with `saveAll`. What can i use so solve my problem?

Everyone thank you for your answers! Andy.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!

```
public function add_datasheet($id = null) {
    $this->set('datasheetsheadings', $this->datasheetsheading->find('all', array('limit' => 0 .','. 9)));
    $this->set('datasheetsheadings2', $this->datasheetsheading->find('all', array('limit' => 9 .','. 9)));
    $this->set('id', $id);
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->datasheet->save($this->request->data)) {
            $last_id = $this->datasheet->id;
            $val_id = 0;
            foreach ($this->request->data['datasheetsvalue'] as $data_val_id) {
                $val_id = $val_id + 1;
                $this->request->data['datasheetsvalue'][$val_id]['id_tbl_datasheets'] = $last_id;
            }
            $this->datasheetsvalue->saveMany($this->request->data['datasheetsvalue']);
            $this->Session->setFlash('Your Datasheet >> Lot: ' . $this->request->data['datasheetsvalue'][1]['value'] . ' << has been saved.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'Datasheets/' . $this->request->data['datasheet']['id_tbl_articles']));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to add your datasheet.');
        }
    }
}
```

I'll use now saveMany. Before, i do a foreach and set datas[] with my var $val_id. Now it works perfect.
Thanks anyway!